# Configuring Spring JMS Listener in grails resources file

Tags: spring, grails, configuration, resources, jms

Is it possible to configure the queue names and corresponding receiver methods in Resources.groovy file? Will the jms plugin pick it up?

What will be the format of below code that can be added to Resources.groovy file?

Following is specified in Springs docs:

```
<jms:listener-container connection-factory="myConnectionFactory"
        task-executor="myTaskExecutor"
        destination-resolver="myDestinationResolver"
        transaction-manager="myTransactionManager"
        concurrency="10">

    <jms:listener destination="queue.orders" ref="orderService" method="placeOrder"/>

    <jms:listener destination="queue.confirmations" ref="confirmationLogger" method="log"/>

</jms:listener-container>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html

Comment: Are you using JMS plugin? http://grails.org/plugin/jms

Comment: Yes.. I am using JMS Plugin

Answer (score 0):

With "JMS plugin" this is not necessary. You can just use the annotation, like the [plugin doc sample](http://gpc.github.io/grails-jms/docs/manual/index.html) ("Topic Listener" session), in your consumer.

Sample (assuming that your factory was properly config in resources.groovy):

```
class ConsumerService {
    boolean transactional = false
    static exposes = ['jms']

    @Subscriber(topic = "my.topic")
    def onMessage(it) {
        println "Topic ... $it"
    }
}
```